# Pandas: Cannot assign NaN using a boolean mask on MultiIndex columns

Tags: pandas, slice, nan, hierarchical-data

First, create this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,-2,3],[4,5,-6],[-7,8,9]],
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [('foo', 'bar'), ('foo', 'baz'), ('ignore', 'other')]))
```

That is:

```
  foo     ignore
  bar baz  other
0   1  -2      3
1   4   5     -6
2  -7   8      9
```

Now, try to replace the negative values under `foo` with NAN:

```
df.foo[df.foo < 0] = np.nan
```

That doesn't do anything but print a warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

OK, let's do that:

```
df.loc[:,'foo'][df.foo < 0] = np.nan
```

That doesn't print a warning, but it also does nothing!

But it works if we use a non-NAN value:

```
df.loc[:,'foo'][df.foo < 0] = 666
```

Now I have:

```
   foo      ignore
   bar  baz  other
0    1  666      3
1    4    5     -6
2  666    8      9
```

But I want to fill with NAN, not 666.  Is there an easy way that works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
sliced = df.loc[:, idx['foo',:]]
print (sliced)
  foo    
  bar baz
0   1  -2
1   4   5
2  -7   8

df.loc[:, idx['foo',:]] = sliced.mask(sliced < 0)
print (df) 
   foo      ignore
   bar  baz  other
0  1.0  NaN      3
1  4.0  5.0     -6
2  NaN  8.0      9
```

Another solution with `concat`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[:, idx['foo',:]]
print (df1)
  foo    
  bar baz
0   1  -2
1   4   5
2  -7   8

df1 = df1.mask(df1 < 0)
print (df1) 
   foo     
   bar  baz
0  1.0  NaN
1  4.0  5.0
2  NaN  8.0

print (pd.concat([df1, df.drop('foo', axis=1, level=0)], axis=1))
   foo      ignore
   bar  baz  other
0  1.0  NaN      3
1  4.0  5.0     -6
2  NaN  8.0      9
```

Comment: This code does work but it is ugly and inefficient (not your fault!).  It has to copy the entire `foo` two times!

Comment: I think `MultiIndex` is a bit complicated, I try add another solution and rewrite old one.

Comment: Unfortunately `sliced = sliced.mask(sliced<0, np.nan)` does not work, need assign to sliced dataframe.